# react native android emulator is not responding

Tags: android-studio, react-native

i'm new to react native and native apps in general and i'm using windows 10.
 i have downloaded java and android studio and configured path variables.
 i have node installed already and used it to get react-native-cli.
 i have initialized a project and troubleshooted all errors.
after running run-android command i get the output of a successful build and it seems like everything should work but the emulator is not responding. i tried API 23 and API 24. does anyone know whats the problem might be?

Comment: Which emulator are you using? The one built into Android studio or Microsoft's one? Have you tried another virtual device? What do you mean by 'not responding' - e.g. does the virtual device boot? Does your app run and then hang"

Comment: i use android studio emulator. i boot it from android studio editor and then run 'react-native run-android' via cmd in the project directory and get a build success output, the emulator itself works fine but not responding to the command. its probably not configured right but i can't find what is it

Comment: There's not a whole lot of configuration that needs to happen to get the emulator to work. Can you run `adb devices` from the command prompt and provide the output? Also, have you tried building and running the project directly from Android Studio?

Comment: i reinstalled android studio which solved the problem. thanks for your time!